# Unrecognized opcode in creating custom RISC-V instruction

Tags: riscv, rocket-chip, riscv32

I've downloaded the `rocket-chip` repo and the corresponding `rocket-tools` repo.  Everything works just fine when I initially build everything.

I've created my own tightly coupled accelerator for the AES algorithm and want to test it using the `custom-0` and `custom-1` instructions.  I've followed the instructions in the `riscv-isa-sim` repo (https://github.com/riscv/riscv-isa-sim) to simulate a new instruction and successfully rebuilt `rocket-tools`.

I want to make a really simple assembly test in `rocket-tools/riscv-tests/isa/rv64ui/` to test my new instructions but when I run `make` in the `isa` folder, I get the `Error: unrecognized opcode` for all my instructions:

```
rv32ui/../rv64ui/aes.S: Assembler messages:
rv32ui/../rv64ui/aes.S:20: Error: unrecognized opcode `wkeyl x14,x1,x2'
rv32ui/../rv64ui/aes.S:21: Error: unrecognized opcode `wkeyh x14,x1,x2'
rv32ui/../rv64ui/aes.S:22: Error: unrecognized opcode `wstatel x14,x1,x2'
rv32ui/../rv64ui/aes.S:23: Error: unrecognized opcode `wstateh x14,x1,x2'
Makefile:74: recipe for target 'rv32ui-p-aes' failed
make: *** [rv32ui-p-aes] Error 1
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
```

What is the correct way to implement custom instructions in RISC-V?  I tried to follow this tutorial but get a segmentation fault when I run spike: https://nitish2112.github.io/post/adding-instruction-riscv/